# Magnolia Solr Confguration

Tags: solr, magnolia

We have magnolia cms which works along with solr for search. I am looking for configuration within magnolia cms to specify which all fields should be searched. Basically, I want more control on the query that gets fired from magnolia to solr.

I have tried searching but havent found anything useful yet. If you can provide any info or pointers then that would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

We have a connector to Solr which you can find the documentation [here](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Solr+module).

Cheers,

Comment: Actually, I have seen that, but could not find any information to give specify fields for the query.

Comment: There are fieldMappings in the configuration, I guess it is what you are looking for: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Indexing+and+crawling+a+website+with+Solr

Comment: No, I am afraid, that is not what I was looking for.

Comment: @OKOK What do you need exactly?